# IllegalStateException: response is not eligible for a body and must not be closed

Tags: okhttp

sometimes we get this exception handling Response.
It seems that Response has a `null` body.

The code is something like:

```
try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
  // do stuff with the response
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Something wrong", e);
}
```

The exception is raised on the `close()` method automatically called on the Response, after the `do stuff with response` block went executed.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: response is not eligible for a body and must not be closed
    at okhttp3.Response.close(Response.java:281)
```

Are we missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting the error with POST requests or any other type?

Comment: only with POST.

Answer (score 2):

I think u can invoke `response.body.close()` which is the same as `response.close()`, and check body is null or not before close.

```
        ResponseBody responseBody = null;
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            responseBody = response.body();
            // do stuff with the response
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Something wrong", e);
        } finally {
            if (responseBody != null) {
                responseBody.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: looks like is the ResponseBody that can be handled with the try-with-resource, because in every case calling the close method on the Response will forward the call to the ResponseBody instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Try with Resources works with Auto-closable (ie classes implement the Closable interface, it tries to call close automatically after the block.

Now the spec for Response close() method, does specify the method would throw and exception in certain cases.

> It is an error to close a response that is not eligible for a body.
>   This includes the responses returned from {@link #cacheResponse},
>   {@link #networkResponse}, and {@link priorResponse()}.

Source:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Response.java

So, it is 'expected' you can just log the details and continue if it is expected. OR handle appropriately (eg: retry) if it is not expected..

Comment: But in our case the response is not "returned from #cacheResponse, #networkResponse, or #priorResponse" so maybe the close() should just close the response without problems?

Comment: If it is consistently happening for a POST which doesn't return any value. Then it would be expected if it is happening inconsistently for the same endpoint then should be dug on whe the response is inconsistent. The best way to narrow down